# Problems with scaling interface from a device to another in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, adaptive-ui

This issue is really frustrating and getting me crazy.

I've read everything about AutoLayout and so on, but it happens all the time.
My interface has a view with an image view as background and a smaller subview on top of it (corresponding to a field in my image). I've tried everything but it looks like the subview does not scale accordingly with my image when switching through devices.
By the way, the IB preview does not show what i real get when running the iOS Simulator, is that normal?
Why? What do i do wrong? I'm not sure what else to try!

http://i58.tinypic.com/34xqtc6.png

EDIT: i cannot post images :(

Comment: the information which you provided is not enough to understand you problem, if you could post images regarding your problem that would be good, if that is not possible could you set up a github repo with you issue, i would gladly have a look

Comment: Hi Usama. i posted a link to a pic above. Let me know if it is clear enough otherwise i'll try to set up a Github repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have setup a githubrepo regarding your case, kindly have a look
https://github.com/usamaiqbal83/TestingProject

[image]

**Constraints for Background Image View:**

[image]

**Constraints for Front View**

[image]

the most important thing to remember is ofcourse the constraint equation

`FirstItem.Attribute1 = (SecondItem.Attribute2 * Multiplier) + Constant`

Comment: i'm trying to learn from the images above: how did u get a proportional constraint?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce manually the constraints u made....some of them are strange to understand to me :S

Comment: Thx so much Usama, i understood what u did. Your solution is the easier one, coz now i have only one background image (the gradient) and a field i will only put on the view i need it!. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subview use Container View.

[image]

Comment: Still showing a displacement :( Can you please suggest me the best way to use constraints in this case? thank so much

Comment: Can you pick another image as your background? Make it all blue and only then add a white square as another view. You can make round corners of this white square with whitesquare.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0 etc.

Comment: Try drawing the frame manually for each screen size. In simulated metrics choose iPhone 4. Place your view and write down the origin, width and height parameters. Do same for iPhone 5 and 6. Later in viewdidload, if view.frame.height = 536.0 make my view with parameters for iPhone 5. Etc.